# vscode vim surround adding spaces when changing from double to single quote

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

Using vscodevim (not the surround extension) in a text file.  When doing the most basic surround example (straight from Tim Pope's surround.vim page).

Press `cs"'` inside

```
"Hello world!"
```

and I expect it to change it to:

```
'Hello world!'
```

however it changes to:

```
' Hello world! '
```

Why those surrounding spaces?  Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in vscodevim?  I am aware of how to avoid these with matching brackets (start bracket versus end bracket) but with quotes?

vscode version: 1.9.1
vscodevim version: 0.5.3

Comment: Probably a bug, so you probably should bring this up over at their GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Will, I'll do that.

Comment: Added Issue to vscodevim: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1336

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/1289

Was already fixed on master, will be in the next release

Comment: Dang, you're even beating me to the punch on StackOverflow. :D